# Start using Migrations mid way through a Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

In the midst of developing a Laravel 4 app, I've decided to start making use of Laravel's Migration feature.

**Question:** Should we write migrations for creating all the tables that we currently have in the database? Or do we only write migrations for future changes?

Comment: I think that every table that 'runs' in the production environment can actually be removed from any migration script (not that I do), I'd say don't bother. Export the current DB and you've got your 'reference state'. After all, that is what migrations are about right? Easily applying changes to databases that don't have the changes yet?

Answer (score 0):

There is no complete right answer to this. It all depends on a lot of variables, like your style of development, how many people you're working with and in what kind of environment (single production DB? multiple dev DBs?), what your requirements with migrations are, etc. etc.

If you **do** decide to write migrations for the entire DB up until this point, you'll need to make sure that your migrations can handle any potential conflicts. Making use of `Schema::has()` and such to verify tables exist prior to attempting to create them, and such.

Alternatively, you can write migrations as if the DB has a clean slate, and enforce any devs to start with an empty DB prior to running migrations. This has risks, so be careful. Make sure you have backups in case your migration forgot something and you need to modify it.

So, TL;DR: Is using migrations for your entire structure part way through a project necessarily a bad thing? No. Is it right for your application? That entirely depends.